# How can I modify abbrvnat.bst to have unsorted reference list using natbib?

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

I like the way `abbrvnat.bst` prints the reference list using the package `natbib`. Unfortunately, it does sort the list alphabetically. How can I modify it such that it prevents the bibliography from being sorted? I want to order citations by appearance. I tried commenting out `ITERATE` and `SORT` in the file `abbrvnat.bst` but it did not work.

If I use `ieeetr`, my problem is solved. However, I have to stick with `natbib` `.bst` files because other `.bst` files such as `ieeetr` are not compatible with `classicthesis` package that I am using. I should only modify `abbrvnat.bst`. I also compared it with the other .bst but I didn't find it trivial what to modify.

Could someone please help me?

---

Here the working example:

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: bibtex
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@preamble{ "\newcommand{\noopsort}[1]{} "}
@ARTICLE{article-full,
   author = {L[eslie] A. Aamport},
   title = {The Gnats and Gnus Document Preparation System},
   journal = {\mbox{G-Animal's} Journal},
   year = 1986,
   volume = 41,
   number = 7,
   pages = "73+",
   month = jul,
   note = "This is a full ARTICLE entry",
}
@BOOK{book-full,
   author = "Donald E. Knuth",
   title = "Seminumerical Algorithms",
   volume = 2,
   series = "The Art of Computer Programming",
   publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
   address = "Reading, Massachusetts",
   edition = "Second",
   month = "10~" # jan,
   year = "1981",
   note = "This is a full BOOK entry",
}
@MISC{misc-full,
   author = "Joe-Bob Missilany",
   title = "Handing out random pamphlets in airports",
   howpublished = "Handed out at O'Hare",
   month = oct,
   year = 1984,
   note = "This is a full MISC entry",
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\begin{document}
\cite{misc-full}
\cite{article-full}
\cite{book-full}

\bibliographystyle{abbrvunsrtnat}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can compare the files `abbrnat.bst` and `unsrtnat.bst` to see the differences. After this you can easily use the file unsrtnat.bst for modifying.

Comment: I edited your question to add an example. My answer is too long and I can't add it there.

Comment: How is a reader supposed to find an abbreviation in a long list of references? With an unsorted style with numeric references it's easy; with abbreviations it requires to go through the entire list each time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Save the following code as `abbrvunsrtnat.bst` in your working directory and use this style:

Here **`abbrvunsrtnat.bst`**

```
%% File: 'abbrvunsrtnat.bst'
%% A modification of 'unsrtnat.bst' and 'abbrnat.bst' 
ENTRY
  { address
    author
    booktitle
    chapter
    doi
    eid
    edition
    editor
    howpublished
    institution
    isbn
    issn
    journal
    key
    month
    note
    number
    organization
    pages
    publisher
    school
    series
    title
    type
    url
    volume
    year
  }
  {}
  { label extra.label sort.label short.list }

INTEGERS { output.state before.all mid.sentence after.sentence after.block }

FUNCTION {init.state.consts}
{ #0 'before.all :=
  #1 'mid.sentence :=
  #2 'after.sentence :=
  #3 'after.block :=
}

STRINGS { s t }

FUNCTION {output.nonnull}
{ 's :=
  output.state mid.sentence =
    { ", " * write$ }
    { output.state after.block =
        { add.period$ write$
          newline$
          "\newblock " write$
        }
        { output.state before.all =
            'write$
            { add.period$ " " * write$ }
          if$
        }
      if$
      mid.sentence 'output.state :=
    }
  if$
  s
}

FUNCTION {output}
{ duplicate$ empty$
    'pop$
    'output.nonnull
  if$
}

FUNCTION {output.check}
{ 't :=
  duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ "empty " t * " in " * cite$ * warning$ }
    'output.nonnull
  if$
}

FUNCTION {fin.entry}
{ add.period$
  write$
  newline$
}

FUNCTION {new.block}
{ output.state before.all =
    'skip$
    { after.block 'output.state := }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {new.sentence}
{ output.state after.block =
    'skip$
    { output.state before.all =
        'skip$
        { after.sentence 'output.state := }
      if$
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {not}
{   { #0 }
    { #1 }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {and}
{   'skip$
    { pop$ #0 }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {or}
{   { pop$ #1 }
    'skip$
  if$
}

FUNCTION {new.block.checka}
{ empty$
    'skip$
    'new.block
  if$
}

FUNCTION {new.block.checkb}
{ empty$
  swap$ empty$
  and
    'skip$
    'new.block
  if$
}

FUNCTION {new.sentence.checka}
{ empty$
    'skip$
    'new.sentence
  if$
}

FUNCTION {new.sentence.checkb}
{ empty$
  swap$ empty$
  and
    'skip$
    'new.sentence
  if$
}

FUNCTION {field.or.null}
{ duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ "" }
    'skip$
  if$
}

FUNCTION {emphasize}
{ duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ "" }
    { "\emph{" swap$ * "}" * }
  if$
}

INTEGERS { nameptr namesleft numnames }

FUNCTION {format.names}
{ 's :=
  #1 'nameptr :=
  s num.names$ 'numnames :=
  numnames 'namesleft :=
    { namesleft #0 > }
    { s nameptr "{f.~}{vv~}{ll}{, jj}" format.name$ 't :=
      nameptr #1 >
        { namesleft #1 >
            { ", " * t * }
            { numnames #2 >
                { "," * }
                'skip$
              if$
              t "others" =
                { " et~al." * }
                { " and " * t * }
              if$
            }
          if$
        }
        't
      if$
      nameptr #1 + 'nameptr :=
      namesleft #1 - 'namesleft :=
    }
  while$
}

FUNCTION {format.key}
{ empty$
    { key field.or.null }
    { "" }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.authors}
{ author empty$
    { "" }
    { author format.names }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.editors}
{ editor empty$
    { "" }
    { editor format.names
      editor num.names$ #1 >
        { ", editors" * }
        { ", editor" * }
      if$
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.isbn}
{ isbn empty$
    { "" }
    { new.block "ISBN " isbn * }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.issn}
{ issn empty$
    { "" }
    { new.block "ISSN " issn * }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.url}
{ url empty$
    { "" }
    { new.block "URL \url{" url * "}" * }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.doi}
{ doi empty$
    { "" }
    { new.block "\doi{" doi * "}" * }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.title}
{ title empty$
    { "" }
    { title "t" change.case$ }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.full.names}
{'s :=
  #1 'nameptr :=
  s num.names$ 'numnames :=
  numnames 'namesleft :=
    { namesleft #0 > }
    { s nameptr
      "{vv~}{ll}" format.name$ 't :=
      nameptr #1 >
        {
          namesleft #1 >
            { ", " * t * }
            {
              numnames #2 >
                { "," * }
                'skip$
              if$
              t "others" =
                { " et~al." * }
                { " and " * t * }
              if$
            }
          if$
        }
        't
      if$
      nameptr #1 + 'nameptr :=
      namesleft #1 - 'namesleft :=
    }
  while$
}

FUNCTION {author.editor.full}
{ author empty$
    { editor empty$
        { "" }
        { editor format.full.names }
      if$
    }
    { author format.full.names }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {author.full}
{ author empty$
    { "" }
    { author format.full.names }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {editor.full}
{ editor empty$
    { "" }
    { editor format.full.names }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {make.full.names}
{ type$ "book" =
  type$ "inbook" =
  or
    'author.editor.full
    { type$ "proceedings" =
        'editor.full
        'author.full
      if$
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {output.bibitem}
{ newline$
  "\bibitem[" write$
  label write$
  ")" make.full.names duplicate$ short.list =
     { pop$ }
     { * }
   if$
  "]{" * write$
  cite$ write$
  "}" write$
  newline$
  ""
  before.all 'output.state :=
}

FUNCTION {n.dashify}
{ 't :=
  ""
    { t empty$ not }
    { t #1 #1 substring$ "-" =
        { t #1 #2 substring$ "--" = not
            { "--" *
              t #2 global.max$ substring$ 't :=
            }
            {   { t #1 #1 substring$ "-" = }
                { "-" *
                  t #2 global.max$ substring$ 't :=
                }
              while$
            }
          if$
        }
        { t #1 #1 substring$ *
          t #2 global.max$ substring$ 't :=
        }
      if$
    }
  while$
}

FUNCTION {format.date}
{ year duplicate$ empty$
    { "empty year in " cite$ * warning$
       pop$ "" }
    'skip$
  if$
  month empty$
    'skip$
    { month
      " " * swap$ *
    }
  if$
  extra.label *
}

FUNCTION {format.btitle}
{ title emphasize
}

FUNCTION {tie.or.space.connect}
{ duplicate$ text.length$ #3 <
    { "~" }
    { " " }
  if$
  swap$ * *
}

FUNCTION {either.or.check}
{ empty$
    'pop$
    { "can't use both " swap$ * " fields in " * cite$ * warning$ }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.bvolume}
{ volume empty$
    { "" }
    { "volume" volume tie.or.space.connect
      series empty$
        'skip$
        { " of " * series emphasize * }
      if$
      "volume and number" number either.or.check
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.number.series}
{ volume empty$
    { number empty$
        { series field.or.null }
        { output.state mid.sentence =
            { "number" }
            { "Number" }
          if$
          number tie.or.space.connect
          series empty$
            { "there's a number but no series in " cite$ * warning$ }
            { " in " * series * }
          if$
        }
      if$
    }
    { "" }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.edition}
{ edition empty$
    { "" }
    { output.state mid.sentence =
        { edition "l" change.case$ " edition" * }
        { edition "t" change.case$ " edition" * }
      if$
    }
  if$
}

INTEGERS { multiresult }

FUNCTION {multi.page.check}
{ 't :=
  #0 'multiresult :=
    { multiresult not
      t empty$ not
      and
    }
    { t #1 #1 substring$
      duplicate$ "-" =
      swap$ duplicate$ "," =
      swap$ "+" =
      or or
        { #1 'multiresult := }
        { t #2 global.max$ substring$ 't := }
      if$
    }
  while$
  multiresult
}

FUNCTION {format.pages}
{ pages empty$
    { "" }
    { pages multi.page.check
        { "pages" pages n.dashify tie.or.space.connect }
        { "page" pages tie.or.space.connect }
      if$
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.eid}
{ eid empty$
    { "" }
    { "art." eid tie.or.space.connect }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.vol.num.pages}
{ volume field.or.null
  number empty$
    'skip$
    { "\penalty0 (" number * ")" * *
      volume empty$
        { "there's a number but no volume in " cite$ * warning$ }
        'skip$
      if$
    }
  if$
  pages empty$
    'skip$
    { duplicate$ empty$
        { pop$ format.pages }
        { ":\penalty0 " * pages n.dashify * }
      if$
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.vol.num.eid}
{ volume field.or.null
  number empty$
    'skip$
    { "\penalty0 (" number * ")" * *
      volume empty$
        { "there's a number but no volume in " cite$ * warning$ }
        'skip$
      if$
    }
  if$
  eid empty$
    'skip$
    { duplicate$ empty$
        { pop$ format.eid }
        { ":\penalty0 " * eid * }
      if$
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.chapter.pages}
{ chapter empty$
    'format.pages
    { type empty$
        { "chapter" }
        { type "l" change.case$ }
      if$
      chapter tie.or.space.connect
      pages empty$
        'skip$
        { ", " * format.pages * }
      if$
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.in.ed.booktitle}
{ booktitle empty$
    { "" }
    { editor empty$
        { "In " booktitle emphasize * }
        { "In " format.editors * ", " * booktitle emphasize * }
      if$
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {empty.misc.check}
{ author empty$ title empty$ howpublished empty$
  month empty$ year empty$ note empty$
  and and and and and
  key empty$ not and
    { "all relevant fields are empty in " cite$ * warning$ }
    'skip$
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.thesis.type}
{ type empty$
    'skip$
    { pop$
      type "t" change.case$
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.tr.number}
{ type empty$
    { "Technical Report" }
    'type
  if$
  number empty$
    { "t" change.case$ }
    { number tie.or.space.connect }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.article.crossref}
{ key empty$
    { journal empty$
        { "need key or journal for " cite$ * " to crossref " * crossref *
          warning$
          ""
        }
        { "In \emph{" journal * "}" * }
      if$
    }
    { "In " }
  if$
  " \citet{" * crossref * "}" *
}

FUNCTION {format.book.crossref}
{ volume empty$
    { "empty volume in " cite$ * "'s crossref of " * crossref * warning$
      "In "
    }
    { "Volume" volume tie.or.space.connect
      " of " *
    }
  if$
  editor empty$
  editor field.or.null author field.or.null =
  or
    { key empty$
        { series empty$
            { "need editor, key, or series for " cite$ * " to crossref " *
              crossref * warning$
              "" *
            }
            { "\emph{" * series * "}" * }
          if$
        }
        'skip$
      if$
    }
    'skip$
  if$
  " \citet{" * crossref * "}" *
}

FUNCTION {format.incoll.inproc.crossref}
{ editor empty$
  editor field.or.null author field.or.null =
  or
    { key empty$
        { booktitle empty$
            { "need editor, key, or booktitle for " cite$ * " to crossref " *
              crossref * warning$
              ""
            }
            { "In \emph{" booktitle * "}" * }
          if$
        }
        { "In " }
      if$
    }
    { "In " }
  if$
  " \citet{" * crossref * "}" *
}

FUNCTION {article}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  author format.key output
  new.block
  format.title "title" output.check
  new.block
  crossref missing$
    { journal emphasize "journal" output.check
      eid empty$
        { format.vol.num.pages output }
        { format.vol.num.eid output }
      if$
      format.date "year" output.check
    }
    { format.article.crossref output.nonnull
      eid empty$
        { format.pages output }
        { format.eid output }
      if$
    }
  if$
  format.issn output
  format.doi output
  format.url output
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {book}
{ output.bibitem
  author empty$
    { format.editors "author and editor" output.check
      editor format.key output
    }
    { format.authors output.nonnull
      crossref missing$
        { "author and editor" editor either.or.check }
        'skip$
      if$
    }
  if$
  new.block
  format.btitle "title" output.check
  crossref missing$
    { format.bvolume output
      new.block
      format.number.series output
      new.sentence
      publisher "publisher" output.check
      address output
    }
    { new.block
      format.book.crossref output.nonnull
    }
  if$
  format.edition output
  format.date "year" output.check
  format.isbn output
  format.doi output
  format.url output
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {booklet}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors output
  author format.key output
  new.block
  format.title "title" output.check
  howpublished address new.block.checkb
  howpublished output
  address output
  format.date output
  format.isbn output
  format.doi output
  format.url output
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {inbook}
{ output.bibitem
  author empty$
    { format.editors "author and editor" output.check
      editor format.key output
    }
    { format.authors output.nonnull
      crossref missing$
        { "author and editor" editor either.or.check }
        'skip$
      if$
    }
  if$
  new.block
  format.btitle "title" output.check
  crossref missing$
    { format.bvolume output
      format.chapter.pages "chapter and pages" output.check
      new.block
      format.number.series output
      new.sentence
      publisher "publisher" output.check
      address output
    }
    { format.chapter.pages "chapter and pages" output.check
      new.block
      format.book.crossref output.nonnull
    }
  if$
  format.edition output
  format.date "year" output.check
  format.isbn output
  format.doi output
  format.url output
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {incollection}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  author format.key output
  new.block
  format.title "title" output.check
  new.block
  crossref missing$
    { format.in.ed.booktitle "booktitle" output.check
      format.bvolume output
      format.number.series output
      format.chapter.pages output
      new.sentence
      publisher "publisher" output.check
      address output
      format.edition output
      format.date "year" output.check
    }
    { format.incoll.inproc.crossref output.nonnull
      format.chapter.pages output
    }
  if$
  format.isbn output
  format.doi output
  format.url output
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {inproceedings}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  author format.key output
  new.block
  format.title "title" output.check
  new.block
  crossref missing$
    { format.in.ed.booktitle "booktitle" output.check
      format.bvolume output
      format.number.series output
      format.pages output
      address empty$
        { organization publisher new.sentence.checkb
          organization output
          publisher output
          format.date "year" output.check
        }
        { address output.nonnull
          format.date "year" output.check
          new.sentence
          organization output
          publisher output
        }
      if$
    }
    { format.incoll.inproc.crossref output.nonnull
      format.pages output
    }
  if$
  format.isbn output
  format.doi output
  format.url output
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {conference} { inproceedings }

FUNCTION {manual}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors output
  author format.key output
  new.block
  format.btitle "title" output.check
  organization address new.block.checkb
  organization output
  address output
  format.edition output
  format.date output
  format.url output
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {mastersthesis}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  author format.key output
  new.block
  format.title "title" output.check
  new.block
  "Master's thesis" format.thesis.type output.nonnull
  school "school" output.check
  address output
  format.date "year" output.check
  format.url output
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {misc}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors output
  author format.key output
  title howpublished new.block.checkb
  format.title output
  howpublished new.block.checka
  howpublished output
  format.date output
  format.issn output
  format.url output
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
  empty.misc.check
}

FUNCTION {phdthesis}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  author format.key output
  new.block
  format.btitle "title" output.check
  new.block
  "PhD thesis" format.thesis.type output.nonnull
  school "school" output.check
  address output
  format.date "year" output.check
  format.url output
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {proceedings}
{ output.bibitem
  format.editors output
  editor format.key output
  new.block
  format.btitle "title" output.check
  format.bvolume output
  format.number.series output
  address output
  format.date "year" output.check
  new.sentence
  organization output
  publisher output
  format.isbn output
  format.doi output
  format.url output
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {techreport}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  author format.key output
  new.block
  format.title "title" output.check
  new.block
  format.tr.number output.nonnull
  institution "institution" output.check
  address output
  format.date "year" output.check
  format.url output
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {unpublished}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  author format.key output
  new.block
  format.title "title" output.check
  new.block
  note "note" output.check
  format.date output
  format.url output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {default.type} { misc }

MACRO {jan} {"Jan."}

MACRO {feb} {"Feb."}

MACRO {mar} {"Mar."}

MACRO {apr} {"Apr."}

MACRO {may} {"May"}

MACRO {jun} {"June"}

MACRO {jul} {"July"}

MACRO {aug} {"Aug."}

MACRO {sep} {"Sept."}

MACRO {oct} {"Oct."}

MACRO {nov} {"Nov."}

MACRO {dec} {"Dec."}



MACRO {acmcs} {"ACM Comput. Surv."}

MACRO {acta} {"Acta Inf."}

MACRO {cacm} {"Commun. ACM"}

MACRO {ibmjrd} {"IBM J. Res. Dev."}

MACRO {ibmsj} {"IBM Syst.~J."}

MACRO {ieeese} {"IEEE Trans. Softw. Eng."}

MACRO {ieeetc} {"IEEE Trans. Comput."}

MACRO {ieeetcad}
 {"IEEE Trans. Comput.-Aided Design Integrated Circuits"}

MACRO {ipl} {"Inf. Process. Lett."}

MACRO {jacm} {"J.~ACM"}

MACRO {jcss} {"J.~Comput. Syst. Sci."}

MACRO {scp} {"Sci. Comput. Programming"}

MACRO {sicomp} {"SIAM J. Comput."}

MACRO {tocs} {"ACM Trans. Comput. Syst."}

MACRO {tods} {"ACM Trans. Database Syst."}

MACRO {tog} {"ACM Trans. Gr."}

MACRO {toms} {"ACM Trans. Math. Softw."}

MACRO {toois} {"ACM Trans. Office Inf. Syst."}

MACRO {toplas} {"ACM Trans. Prog. Lang. Syst."}

MACRO {tcs} {"Theoretical Comput. Sci."}

READ

FUNCTION {sortify}
{ purify$
  "l" change.case$
}

INTEGERS { len }

FUNCTION {chop.word}
{ 's :=
  'len :=
  s #1 len substring$ =
    { s len #1 + global.max$ substring$ }
    's
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.lab.names}
{ 's :=
  s #1 "{vv~}{ll}" format.name$
  s num.names$ duplicate$
  #2 >
    { pop$ " et~al." * }
    { #2 <
        'skip$
        { s #2 "{ff }{vv }{ll}{ jj}" format.name$ "others" =
            { " et~al." * }
            { " and " * s #2 "{vv~}{ll}" format.name$ * }
          if$
        }
      if$
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {author.key.label}
{ author empty$
    { key empty$
        { cite$ #1 #3 substring$ }
        'key
      if$
    }
    { author format.lab.names }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {author.editor.key.label}
{ author empty$
    { editor empty$
        { key empty$
            { cite$ #1 #3 substring$ }
            'key
          if$
        }
        { editor format.lab.names }
      if$
    }
    { author format.lab.names }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {author.key.organization.label}
{ author empty$
    { key empty$
        { organization empty$
            { cite$ #1 #3 substring$ }
            { "The " #4 organization chop.word #3 text.prefix$ }
          if$
        }
        'key
      if$
    }
    { author format.lab.names }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {editor.key.organization.label}
{ editor empty$
    { key empty$
        { organization empty$
            { cite$ #1 #3 substring$ }
            { "The " #4 organization chop.word #3 text.prefix$ }
          if$
        }
        'key
      if$
    }
    { editor format.lab.names }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {calc.short.authors}
{ type$ "book" =
  type$ "inbook" =
  or
    'author.editor.key.label
    { type$ "proceedings" =
        'editor.key.organization.label
        { type$ "manual" =
            'author.key.organization.label
            'author.key.label
          if$
        }
      if$
    }
  if$
  'short.list :=
}

FUNCTION {calc.label}
{ calc.short.authors
  short.list
  "("
  *
  year duplicate$ empty$
  short.list key field.or.null = or
     { pop$ "" }
     'skip$
  if$
  *
  'label :=
}

INTEGERS { seq.num }

FUNCTION {init.seq}
{ #0 'seq.num :=}

EXECUTE {init.seq}

FUNCTION {int.to.fix}
{ "000000000" swap$ int.to.str$ *
  #-1 #10 substring$
}


FUNCTION {presort}
{ calc.label
  label sortify
  "    "
  *
  seq.num #1 + 'seq.num :=
  seq.num  int.to.fix
  'sort.label :=
  sort.label *
  #1 entry.max$ substring$
  'sort.key$ :=
}

ITERATE {presort}

SORT

STRINGS { longest.label last.label next.extra }

INTEGERS { longest.label.width last.extra.num number.label }

FUNCTION {initialize.longest.label}
{ "" 'longest.label :=
  #0 int.to.chr$ 'last.label :=
  "" 'next.extra :=
  #0 'longest.label.width :=
  #0 'last.extra.num :=
  #0 'number.label :=
}

FUNCTION {forward.pass}
{ last.label label =
    { last.extra.num #1 + 'last.extra.num :=
      last.extra.num int.to.chr$ 'extra.label :=
    }
    { "a" chr.to.int$ 'last.extra.num :=
      "" 'extra.label :=
      label 'last.label :=
    }
  if$
  number.label #1 + 'number.label :=
}

FUNCTION {reverse.pass}
{ next.extra "b" =
    { "a" 'extra.label := }
    'skip$
  if$
  extra.label 'next.extra :=
  extra.label
  duplicate$ empty$
    'skip$
    { "{\natexlab{" swap$ * "}}" * }
  if$
  'extra.label :=
  label extra.label * 'label :=
}

EXECUTE {initialize.longest.label}

ITERATE {forward.pass}

REVERSE {reverse.pass}

FUNCTION {bib.sort.order}
{ sort.label  'sort.key$ :=
}

ITERATE {bib.sort.order}

SORT

FUNCTION {begin.bib}
{   preamble$ empty$
    'skip$
    { preamble$ write$ newline$ }
  if$
  "\begin{thebibliography}{" number.label int.to.str$ * "}" *
  write$ newline$
  "\providecommand{\natexlab}[1]{#1}"
  write$ newline$
  "\providecommand{\url}[1]{\texttt{#1}}"
  write$ newline$
  "\expandafter\ifx\csname urlstyle\endcsname\relax"
  write$ newline$
  "  \providecommand{\doi}[1]{doi: #1}\else"
  write$ newline$
  "  \providecommand{\doi}{doi: \begingroup \urlstyle{rm}\Url}\fi"
  write$ newline$
}

EXECUTE {begin.bib}

EXECUTE {init.state.consts}

ITERATE {call.type$}

FUNCTION {end.bib}
{ newline$
  "\end{thebibliography}" write$ newline$
}

EXECUTE {end.bib}
```