# Problem in compression of multiple citations using abbrvunsrtnat.bst

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, classicthesis

I had a problem in modifying `abbrvnat.bst` to have unsorted abbreviated reference list using `natbib`. Many thanks to @Marco Daniel for [his great answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/106169/23594). He perfectly solved my problem by creating `abbrvunsrtnat.bst`.

Currently, I have a problem in compressing multiple citations by using `abbrvunsrtnat.bst`. For example, I am not able to see `[8,17-20]` when the citation list is `[8,17,18,19,20]`. I tried `sort&compress` option to `natlib` package but it did not change anything. I am using all these in `classicthesis` package.

As an example, the following code does not produce the compressed citation.

```
\documentclass[
                twoside, openright, titlepage, numbers=noenddot, headinclude,
                footinclude=true, cleardoublepage=empty,
                BCOR=5mm, paper=letter, fontsize=11pt,
                dottedtoc,
                ngerman, american,
                ]{scrreprt} 
\usepackage[position=t,singlelinecheck=off,font={it}]{subfig}
\usepackage[eulerchapternumbers,
                    listings,
                    pdfspacing,
                    subfig,
                    beramono,
                    parts]{classicthesis}

\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}

\begin{document}
\cite{article-full,book-full,misc-full}
\bibliographystyle{abbrvunsrtnat}
\bibliography{Ahmad}
\end{document}
```

The following is the resulted document.

[image]

Here is the log of `\listfiles`:

```
*File List*
    scrreprt.cls    2012/07/29 v3.11b KOMA-Script document class (report)
    scrkbase.sty    2012/07/29 v3.11b KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-dependent ba
    sics and keyval usage)
     scrbase.sty    2012/07/29 v3.11b KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-independent 
    basics and keyval usage)
      keyval.sty    1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
    scrlfile.sty    2012/06/15 v3.12 KOMA-Script package (loading files)
    tocbasic.sty    2012/04/04 v3.10b KOMA-Script package (handling toc-files)
    scrsize11pt.clo    2012/07/29 v3.11b KOMA-Script font size class option (11pt)
    typearea.sty    2012/07/29 v3.11b KOMA-Script package (type area)
      subfig.sty    2005/06/28 ver: 1.3 subfig package
     caption.sty    2013/04/14 v3.3-73 Customizing captions (AR)
    caption3.sty    2013/04/14 v1.5-71 caption3 kernel (AR)
    classicthesis.sty    2012/08/12 v4.1 Typographic style for a classic-looking th
    esis
      ifthen.sty    2001/05/26 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
    listings.sty    2007/02/22 1.4 (Carsten Heinz)
     lstmisc.sty    2007/02/22 1.4 (Carsten Heinz)
    listings.cfg    2007/02/22 1.4 listings configuration
       ifpdf.sty    2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
    hyperref.sty    2012/11/06 v6.83m Hypertext links for LaTeX
    hobsub-hyperref.sty    2012/04/25 v1.12 Bundle oberdiek, subset hyperref (HO)
    hobsub-generic.sty    2012/04/25 v1.12 Bundle oberdiek, subset generic (HO)
      hobsub.sty    2012/04/25 v1.12 Construct package bundles (HO)
    infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
     ltxcmds.sty    2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
    ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
      ifvtex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.5 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
     intcalc.sty    2007/09/27 v1.1 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
    etexcmds.sty    2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
    kvsetkeys.sty    2012/04/25 v1.16 Key value parser (HO)
    kvdefinekeys.sty    2011/04/07 v1.3 Define keys (HO)
    pdftexcmds.sty    2011/11/29 v0.20 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
    pdfescape.sty    2011/11/25 v1.13 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
    bigintcalc.sty    2012/04/08 v1.3 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO)
      bitset.sty    2011/01/30 v1.1 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)
    uniquecounter.sty    2011/01/30 v1.2 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
    letltxmacro.sty    2010/09/02 v1.4 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
     hopatch.sty    2011/06/24 v1.1 Wrapper for package hooks (HO)
    xcolor-patch.sty    2011/01/30 xcolor patch
    atveryend.sty    2011/06/30 v1.8 Hooks at the very end of document (HO)
    atbegshi.sty    2011/10/05 v1.16 At begin shipout hook (HO)
    refcount.sty    2011/10/16 v3.4 Data extraction from label references (HO)
     hycolor.sty    2011/01/30 v1.7 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
     ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
     auxhook.sty    2011/03/04 v1.3 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
    kvoptions.sty    2011/06/30 v3.11 Key value format for package options (HO)
      pd1enc.def    2012/11/06 v6.83m Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
    hyperref.cfg    2002/06/06 v1.2 hyperref configuration of TeXLive
         url.sty    2006/04/12  ver 3.3  Verb mode for urls, etc.
     hpdftex.def    2012/11/06 v6.83m Hyperref driver for pdfTeX
    rerunfilecheck.sty    2011/04/15 v1.7 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
      xcolor.sty    2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
       color.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
      pdftex.def    2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX
    dvipsnam.def    1999/02/16 v3.0i Driver-dependant file (DPC,SPQR)
    mathpazo.sty    2005/04/12 PSNFSS-v9.2a Palatino w/ Pazo Math (D.Puga, WaS) 
    beramono.sty    2004/01/31 (WaS)
    microtype.sty    2013/03/13 v2.5 Micro-typographical refinements (RS)
    microtype-pdftex.def    2013/03/13 v2.5 Definitions specific to pdftex (RS)
    microtype.cfg    2013/03/13 v2.5 microtype main configuration file (RS)
    booktabs.sty    2005/04/14 v1.61803 publication quality tables
    textcase.sty    2004/10/07 v0.07 Text only upper/lower case changing (DPC)
    scrpage2.sty    2010/04/22 v2.5 LaTeX2e KOMA-Script package
    titlesec.sty    2011/12/15 v2.10.0 Sectioning titles
     tocloft.sty    2013/05/02 v2.3f parameterised ToC, etc., typesetting
     scrtime.sty    2012/07/29 v3.11b KOMA-Script package (time of LaTeX run)
    remreset.sty    
      natbib.sty    2000/07/24 7.0a (PWD)
     ot1pplj.fd    2004/09/06 font definitions for OT1/pplj.
     nameref.sty    2012/10/27 v2.43 Cross-referencing by name of section
    gettitlestring.sty    2010/12/03 v1.4 Cleanup title references (HO)
       alaki.out
       alaki.out
    supp-pdf.mkii
      mt-ppl.cfg    2005/11/16 v1.6 microtype config. file: Palatino (RS)
       alaki.bbl
```

Could someone help me compress the citation list by using `abbrvunsrtnat.bst`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by wrong version of `natbib`, which was `natbib.sty 2000/07/24 7.0a (PWD)`. I had to manually update it to 
`natbib 2010/09/13 8.31b (PWD, AO)`. Another thing was that, I had installed `jfm` package which had `natbib` with the version `2000/07/24 7.0a (PWD)` in its directory. I deleted the `natbib.sty` file in the `jfm` directory as it had conflict with the new version. After that it worked perfectly and my citations were nicely compressed.

Many thanks to the chat I had with @mafp.

Answer (score 1):

The following works for me:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}

\begin{document}
\cite{article-full,book-full,misc-full}
\bibliographystyle{abbrvunsrtnat}
\bibliography{Ahmad}
\end{document}
```

[image: sample output]

Comment: Thanks. Your code works perfectly. In my original question, I added a sample code which uses both `natbib` and `classicthesis`. Unfortunately, it does not produce a compressed citation.

Comment: @Ahmad I compiled your sample code and it shows compressed citations. (classicthesis version 4.1)

Comment: I am using the same version but I don't get the compressed citation. Here is the information in the log file: `Package: classicthesis 2012/08/12 v4.1 Typographic style for a classic-looking 
thesis`. Could it be something else that prevents compression of citation?

Comment: @Ahmad Sorry if I ask stupid things, but is your TeX installation up-to-date? I don't see any package that should interfere with `natbib`. You could put `\listfiles` at the very first line into your document. Then the `log` file will list all loaded packages with their versions. You could add this list to your question, and we can compare versions.

Comment: Thanks. It was my guess too. So I updated MiKTeX a few hours ago. However, I have added the file lists to the question.

Comment: @Ahmad I compared, and my package versions are the same. The last idea is to clean out the auxiliary files: remove `alaki.aux` and `alaki.bbl`, then rerun `pdflatex`, `bibtex`, `pdflatex`, `pdflatex` (however you do this with MiKTeX).

Comment: @@mafp: I had tried this before. I tried it a few more times and it didn't work. :(((

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8867/discussion-between-ahmad-and-mafp)